# Telegram bot can't receive multiple pics at one message

Tags: python, image, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to setup a telegram bot for receiving multiple images in one message. My bot can receive only the first image, all others are ignored. Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import config
import telebot
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton,  InputMediaPhoto

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)
main_menu_keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True,True)
main_menu_keyboard.add('test1', 'test2')

welcome_message='''Hello,
dude
'''

dict = {}

class nameDict:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.media = None


def process_name_step(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        name = message.text
        upload = nameDict(name)
        dict[chat_id] = upload
        message = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Upload your photos: ')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_media_step)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Error...')

def process_media_step(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        media = message.photo[-1].file_id
        upload = dict[chat_id]
        upload.media = media
        bot.send_photo(chat_id, str(upload.media))
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Error...')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_media_step)

bot.enable_save_next_step_handlers(delay=2)
bot.load_next_step_handlers()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, welcome_message, reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'test1':
        message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Enter youe name: ')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_name_step)

    elif message.text.lower() == 'test2':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Empty')

bot.polling()
```

Could you please me find a solution on how to receive multiple images in a single message to the bot?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround just add a photo handler that saves them locally.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def get_photo(message):
    fileID = message.photo[-1].file_id
    file_info = bot.get_file(fileID)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    user_path=str(message.from_user.id)
    if not os.path.exists(user_path):
      os.makedirs(user_path)
    with open(str(message.from_user.id) + '/' + fileID, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
```